# Refused to get unsafe header "Server-Timing" when Timing-Allow-Origin is set to *?

Tags: http, salesforce, response-headers

I'm trying to embed some Salesforce code, which is working fine on Edge, and some versions of Google Chrome, but some others are giving me the `Refused to get unsafe header "Server-Timing"` error, even though when checking the Response Headers on Edge I can see both `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Server-Timing` and `Timing-Allow-Origin: *` are included.

I've tried looking around a bit, but there doesn't seem to be a lot regarding this, I'm unsure if this is something I can chock up to a current version of Chrome bug, or if it's something I'd need to bring to Salesforce.

Comment: Experiencing the same with Salesforce chat, did you find an issue?

Comment: How did you solve this issue.